# What Is All Of This Stuff In My Sent Email From Hotmail?

Tags: security, email, html, javascript, hotmail

I sent an email from my Hotmail account to myself and viewed the source.  I did this from www.Hotmail.com and sent only the text 'Test'.

When I received the email, I viewed the source in Outlook and this is what I saw:

```
<html>
<head>
<style><!--
.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 10pt;
font-family:Tahoma
}
--></style>
</head>
<body class='hmmessage'>
Test<script>try{if (typeof(lpcurruser) == 'undefined') lpcurruser = ''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt') && document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value != '') { lpcurruser = document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value = ''; } if (typeof(lpcurrpass) == 'undefined') lpcurrpass=''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt') && document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value != '') { lpcurrpass = document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value = ''; } var lploc=1;var lponlyfill=1;var link=document.getElementById("i1668"); if(link&&typeof(g_lpclicked)=="undefined"){if(document.createEventObject){var evt = document.createEventObject();link.fireEvent("onclick",evt);}else{var evt2 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");evt2.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);link.dispatchEvent(evt2);}g_lpclicked=1;}lpcurruser = ''; lpcurrpass = '';}catch(e){}</script><script>try{if (typeof(lpcurruser) == 'undefined') lpcurruser = ''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt') && document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value != '') { lpcurruser = document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value = ''; } if (typeof(lpcurrpass) == 'undefined') lpcurrpass=''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt') && document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value != '') { lpcurrpass = document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value = ''; } var lploc=2;var lponlyfill=1;var link=document.getElementById("i1668"); if(link&&typeof(g_lpclicked)=="undefined"){if(document.createEventObject){var evt = document.createEventObject();link.fireEvent("onclick",evt);}else{var evt2 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");evt2.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);link.dispatchEvent(evt2);}g_lpclicked=1;}lpcurruser = ''; lpcurrpass = '';}catch(e){}</script><script>try{if (typeof(lpcurruser) == 'undefined') lpcurruser = ''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt') && document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value != '') { lpcurruser = document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value = ''; } if (typeof(lpcurrpass) == 'undefined') lpcurrpass=''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt') && document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value != '') { lpcurrpass = document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value = ''; } var lploc=1;var lponlyfill=1;var link=document.getElementById("i1668"); if(link&&typeof(g_lpclicked)=="undefined"){if(document.createEventObject){var evt = document.createEventObject();link.fireEvent("onclick",evt);}else{var evt2 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");evt2.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);link.dispatchEvent(evt2);}g_lpclicked=1;}lpcurruser = ''; lpcurrpass = '';}catch(e){}</script><script>try{if (typeof(lpcurruser) == 'undefined') lpcurruser = ''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt') && document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value != '') { lpcurruser = document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value = ''; } if (typeof(lpcurrpass) == 'undefined') lpcurrpass=''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt') && document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value != '') { lpcurrpass = document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value = ''; } var lploc=2;var lponlyfill=1;var link=document.getElementById("i1668"); if(link&&typeof(g_lpclicked)=="undefined"){if(document.createEventObject){var evt = document.createEventObject();link.fireEvent("onclick",evt);}else{var evt2 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");evt2.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, document.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);link.dispatchEvent(evt2);}g_lpclicked=1;}lpcurruser = ''; lpcurrpass = '';}catch(e){}</script>                      </body>
</html>
```

**What Is That?!?!**

It looks, suspicious to say the least.  Does anyone know what lpcurrpass is?

EDIT:  What about sending an e-mail from Hotmail is offtopic for Super User?  Is there a more appropriate place to ask such questions?

Comment: I don't think it's offtopic. From [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about … [..] **computer software**". Since your topic isn't specifically related to the "webmail service" Hotmail, it would fit better here than at [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For computer enthusiasts and power users interpreting Javascript code is considered off-topic. For me, the question would fit best on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) asked like "What does this script that I found in Outlook do?" or something along that line. But there tends to be some disagreement because mentioning Hotmail is more for the Web Apps site. Viewing the source with Outlook could be seen as an afterthought, you have a problem with the source (Stack Overflow) that is generated on Hotmail (Web Apps) but no problems with Outlook (Super User) itself...

Comment: I would like to suggest to choose between those two sites and flag your question to be reopened and migrated there. Or just leave it as is as the current answer most likely answers it for you... :)

Answer (score 5):

Googling for `typeof(lpcurruser)` revealed that it could possibly come from [LastPass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LastPass), a password manager.

A user posted the [next post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fforums.lastpass.com%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D14%26t%3D76682) on their forums (note: the link is from Google cache as you need to be registered in order to read it):

> If I edit a document on Facebook using Firefox 3.6.16 and using the latest LastPass plugin this is appended to the text field prior to save every time for any document. By document I am referring to documents created in the Docs section. This does not occur in other fields or with Chrome.
>
> The search feature is not working for any forums here now so I don't know if this is a known bug.
>
> [the same code as in your question]